# Cast an object into generic list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement where I can get the following in an object -

```
a type T or List<T>
```

Converting object into T is easy. How can I convert it to List(by first checking that it can be converted successfully or not), reason I want to convert is to scroll through the list and call tostring on each element.

My actual code -

```
namespace Generic_Collection_Code
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string DumpObj(object obj)
        {
            string sTemp = String.Empty;

            List<int> ints = obj as List<int>;
            if (ints != null)
            {
                foreach (int i in ints)
                    sTemp += i.ToString() + ",";
                sTemp.Trim(',');
            }
            else 
            {
                List<string> strings = obj as List<string>;
                if (strings != null)
                {
                    foreach (string s in strings)
                        sTemp += s + ",";
                    sTemp.Trim(',');
                }
                else
                {
                    sTemp += obj.ToString();
                }
            }
            return sTemp;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> listInts = new List<int>();
            listInts.Add(1);
            listInts.Add(2);
            listInts.Add(3);

            Console.WriteLine("Object1: {0}", DumpObj(listInts));
            int i = 90;

            Console.WriteLine("Object2 {0}", DumpObj(i));


            List<string> listStrings = new List<string>();
            listStrings.Add("1");
            listStrings.Add("2");
            listStrings.Add("3");

            Console.WriteLine("Object3: {0}", DumpObj(listStrings));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works but I know its an ugly way to achieve this. I wanted to ask from community how can I have this function like -

```
    public static string DumpObj<T>(object obj)
    {
        string sTemp = String.Empty;

        List<T> list = obj as List<T>;
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (T i in list)
                sTemp += i.ToString() + ",";
            sTemp.Trim(',');
        }
        return sTemp;
    }
```

This gives me compilation errors as I have to specify T while calling DumpObj with error as -

Error   1   The type arguments for method 'Generic_Collection_Code.Program.DumpObj(object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. D:\DotNet\Generic_Collection_Code\Generic_Collection_Code\Program.cs    57  47  Generic_Collection_Code

as you can see, obj is an object, i dont know its type while calling dumobj.

I hope I have made myself clear on this one.

I appreciate your time!

Regards
Amit

Comment: Rex M, your edit should be an answer.  As it stands it makes the question nonsensical because changing List to List<T> probably fixes the main issue the asker is having.

Comment: I agree that the edit materially changes the question. My understanding is that he had a variable of type "object", and he does not know what type it is. But if it is a List<T>, then he wants to loop over it.

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code ... several of us are interpreting it differently and it seems like the question was edited in a way that changed it. Can you increase the scope of your code sample to include the signature of the class and method you're working inside of?

Comment: Amit, see my answer.  Because ToString is defined on System.Object you can try to use `obj` as an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is the compilation error you're getting?  If T is declared as a generic type parameter in your context then then the only compile-time issue I can see with that statement is the use of the keyword `object` as a variable name.  At any rate, I'd suggest something like this as best expressing your intention:

```
IEnumerable enumerable = obj as IEnumerable;

if (enumerable != null)
{
    foreach (object item in enumerable)
    {
        sTemp += item.ToString();
    }
}
```

You may also want to consider using a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) if your list is likely to have a lot of items.

Comment: your comment was the right answer all the way long. I was stupid enough not to IEnumerable, I kept using IEnumerable<T>. Also, I have also taken your advice of using StringBuilder into my program as it might be called large no of times.
Thanks a ton for your time!

Answer (score 11):

Say

```
List<T> genericList = object as List<T>;

if(genericList != null)
{
   // Do the loop
}
```

The "as" keyword verifies that "object" actually "is-a" List< T >. If so, you get a List< T >  back from it. If not, you get null.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely right. If you can't have the 'class' constraint, then you can say: if(typeof(List<T>).IsAssignableFrom(object.GetType())).

Comment: I'm confused, why should T have to be a class to make a list out of it?

Comment: We're not making a list out of it. We have an object, and all we know about it is that it inherits from System.Object (as everything does). So, we're performing a runtime check to see if it actually is a List< T >. If it is, then we cast it to List< T > and then iterate it.

Comment: BTW, the question has been edited in a way that significantly changes it. The original version had a variable of type object, and he was casting it to List< T >.

Comment: Oh, and the part about "having to be a class" ... you cannot use the "as" operator on a value type. It has to be a reference type, which means it must have the "class" constraint.

Comment: Oh, and when I said "make a list out of it" I guess it would've been clearer to say "construct concrete List<>".

Answer (score 4):

you cant do this

```
List<T> genericList = (List<T>)object
```

might be you want

```
List<T> genericList = (List<T>)obj
```

where obj is object

Comment: <pre>
Actual code
string DumpObj(object obj) 
{
 List<T> glist = obj as List<T>;  
 // cant recognize T, because its not a generic function, even if I make it as generic one, I cannot call it as 
 at the time of sending the object I am not sure what type will it have, it might not have a list at all

Comment: I think we need to see more of your code ... several of us are interpreting it differently and it seems like the question was edited in a way that changed it. Can you increase the scope of your code sample to include the signature of the class and method you're working inside of?

Answer (score 0):

How about combining "as" with "is"?

```
if (object is List<T>)
{ 
  List<T> genericlist = object as List<T>;
 // loop list
}
else if (object is T)
{
 // do something else
}
```

Comment: If @object *is* a List<T> then you might as well just cast directly to List<T> once you know.

Answer (score 0):

How about casting the Object into System.Collections.IList (instead of the Generic version) because Generic list also implement this interface. Then cast each of them into the desired type.
Here is what I am working on..

```
private static void DataSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,     
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
        BarChart _ = sender as BarChart;

        if (args.Property.Equals(BarChart.DataSourceProperty)) {
            System.Collections.IList data = (System.Collections.IList)args.NewValue;
            if (data == null) return;

            foreach (object __ in data) {
                IChartDataItem item = __ as IChartDataItem;
                BarChartItem bar = new BarChartItem() {
                    Label = item.Label,
                    Value = item.Value
                };
                _._visualCollection.Add(bar);

                if (_.MaxData < item.Value)
                    _.MaxData = item.Value;
            }

            if (_.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
                _.Ratio = _.Width / _.MaxData;
        }
    }
```